# Running Selenium as a service with multiple users

Tags: selenium

I want to run Selenium on a Windows server and have multiple testers connect to it.

1. If two users connect at the same time and both ask to run a test against a browser, will Selenium start two separate instances of the browser and run the two sets of tests independently? What if the browser requested is IE?
2. If two users are connected at the same time, can one see what tests the other is running?

Comment: I have a similar situation. could someone please explain the solution for this situation.
how to run "multiple virtual machines being hosted on a single server". how it will work? Seriously searching for the solution. any suggestions would be great. Thanks lot in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Generally this is not a good idea. Your users will be competing for computer resources and there is the potential of having "session corruption" where one browser affects the other when authentication and server side session state, and system dialogue boxes are factored in.

You should use multiple virtual machines being hosted on a single server.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with having multiple users share a Selenium RC server for non-Internet Explorer browsers.  It works just fine.  The server will start up independent browsers and the tests will be completely isolated.

For Internet Explorer, it can't be done.  IE tries very hard to maintain a single browser instance for each logged-in user (*i.e.*, each Windows "session").  Your only option with IE is to have separate Selenium RC servers running in separate sessions.